# How to resolve the Error " Unable to locate local.config.user file. Make sure you have run 'build.cmd local' '

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

i am trying to run this test on local host, but it keeps throwing the error " Unable to locate local.config.user file.  Make sure you have run 'build.cmd local'"

So how do I locate local.config.user file? Or how to run build.cmd local ? Please try see Code below

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

namespace Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Applications.RemoteMonitoring.Common.Configurations
{
    public class ConfigurationProvider : IConfigurationProvider, IDisposable
    {
        readonly Dictionary<string, string> configuration = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        EnvironmentDescription environment = null;
        const string ConfigToken = "config:";
        bool _disposed = false;

        public string GetConfigurationSettingValue(string configurationSettingName)
        {
            return this.GetConfigurationSettingValueOrDefault(configurationSettingName, string.Empty);
        }

        public string GetConfigurationSettingValueOrDefault(string configurationSettingName, string defaultValue)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!this.configuration.ContainsKey(configurationSettingName))
                {
                    string configValue = string.Empty;
                    bool isEmulated = true;
                    bool isAvailable = false;
                    try
                    {
                        isAvailable = RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable;
                    }
                    catch (TypeInitializationException) { }
                    if (isAvailable)
                    {
                        configValue = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configurationSettingName);
                        isEmulated = RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        configValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configurationSettingName];
                        isEmulated = Environment.CommandLine.Contains("iisexpress.exe") ||
                            Environment.CommandLine.Contains("WebJob.vshost.exe");
                    }
                    if (isEmulated && (configValue != null && configValue.StartsWith(ConfigToken, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                    {
                        if (environment == null)
                        {
                            LoadEnvironmentConfig();
                        }

                        configValue = 
                            environment.GetSetting(configValue.Substring(configValue.IndexOf(ConfigToken, StringComparison.Ordinal) + ConfigToken.Length));
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        this.configuration.Add(configurationSettingName, configValue);
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        // at this point, this key has already been added on a different
                        // thread, so we're fine to continue
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (RoleEnvironmentException)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultValue))
                    throw;

                this.configuration.Add(configurationSettingName, defaultValue);
            }
            return this.configuration[configurationSettingName];
        }

        void LoadEnvironmentConfig()
        {
            var executingPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);

            // Check for build_output
            int buildLocation = executingPath.IndexOf("Build_Output", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (buildLocation >= 0)
            {
                string fileName = executingPath.Substring(0, buildLocation) + "local.config.user";
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    this.environment = new EnvironmentDescription(fileName);
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Web roles run in there app dir so look relative
            int location = executingPath.IndexOf("Web\\bin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (location == -1)
            {
                location = executingPath.IndexOf("WebJob\\bin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }
           if (location >=0)
            {
              string fileName = executingPath.Substring(0, location) + "..\\local.config.user";
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    this.environment = new EnvironmentDescription(fileName);
                    return;
                }
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to locate local.config.user file.  Make sure you have run 'build.cmd local'.");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                if (environment != null)
                {
                    environment.Dispose();
                }
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }

        ~ConfigurationProvider()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi sir, thank you for your help. I have tried "Build.cmd build" and "Build.cmd local" it gave me this error.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in the root folder of your Visual Studio solution you should have a `build.cmd` file.

You need to run `Developer Command Prompt for VS2015` (or with an another version of installed Visual Studio, use Windows Search in the Start menu) as an Administrator and change directory (`cd [directory with solution]`) to the root folder of mentioned solution and then type and run `build.cmd local` by clicking Enter.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you very much for the help. I have updated my question, am i missing a file?

Comment: @nicko_yuan Hello, sorry for this late response, as you see build.cmd does not like spaces in the path. Try to rename your folder "Visual Studio Projects" to "VSProjects" (or "VisualStudioProjects", but I suggest to keep it short as there are limits for path length) and it should work after.